# Show that $\mathbb E[Y^p]=\int_0^\infty py^{p-1}\mathbb P\{Y\geq y\}\mathrm d y.$

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $Y\geq 0$ a r.v. Show that 
$$\mathbb E[Y^p]=\int_0^\infty  py^{p-1}\mathbb P\{Y\geq y\}\mathrm d y.$$

I have that $$\mathbb E[Y^p]=\int_0^\infty Y^p\mathrm d \mathbb P,$$
how can I continue ?

Comment: Integrate by parts.

Comment: First you should show that $E[Y]=\int_0^\infty P(Y \geq y) dy$. Then try to make a substitution...

Comment: The expression $\int_0^\infty Y^p \mathsf d\mathbb P$ is only meaningful if the underlying probability space $\Omega=[0,\infty)$ - which is certainly not a necessary assumption for this identity.

Comment: This was asked many times already... The reduction to the case $p=1$ is not necessary, simply integrate the LHS and the RHS of the pointwise identity $$Y^p=\int_0^Y py^{p-1}\,dy=\int_0^\infty py^{p-1}\mathbf 1_{Y\geqslant y}\,dy$$

Answer (score 1):

For $k\geqslant 1$ and $t\geqslant 0$, the map $(t,\omega)\mapsto kt^{k-1}\mathsf 1_{\{\omega:X(\omega)\geqslant t\}}$ is measurable as the product of measurable functions, and because it is nonnegative, from Tonelli's theorem we have
\begin{align}
\int_{[0,\infty)\times\Omega}  kt^{k-1}\mathsf 1_{\{\omega:X(\omega)\geqslant t\}}\mathsf d(t\times\mathbb P(\omega)) &= \int_0^\infty kt^{k-1} \int_\Omega \mathsf 1_{\{\omega:X(\omega)\geqslant t\}}\,\mathsf d\mathbb P(\omega)\,\mathsf dt\\
&= \int_0^\infty kt^{k-1}\mathbb E\left[\mathsf 1_{\{\omega:X(\omega)\geqslant t\}}\right]\,\mathsf dt\\
&= \int_0^\infty kt^{k-1}\mathbb P(X\geqslant t)\,\mathsf dt,
\end{align}
and also
\begin{align}
\int_{[0,\infty)\times\Omega}  kt^{k-1}\mathsf 1_{\{\omega:X(\omega)\geqslant t\}}\,\mathsf d(t\times\mathbb P(\omega)) &= \int_\Omega \int_0^\infty  kt^{k-1}\mathsf 1_{\{\omega:X(\omega)\geqslant t\}}\,\mathsf dt\,\mathsf d\mathbb P(\omega) \\
 &= \int_\Omega \int_0^{X(\omega)}kt^{k-1}\,\mathsf dt\,\mathsf d\mathbb P(\omega)\\
&= \int_\Omega X(\omega)^k\,\mathsf d\mathbb P(\omega)\\
&= \mathbb E\left[X^k\right].
\end{align}
It follows that
$$\mathbb E\left[X^k\right] = \int_0^\infty kt^{k-1}\mathbb P(X\geqslant t)\,\mathsf dt. $$